# XCUITests fail on m1 Mac: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, apple-m1, xcuitest

I have a perfectly fine running UITest target in my app that runs fine on the Intel based old Mac.

If I take the pull of this same code in my M1 Mac, the UITests fail even before execution.

The app is launched when the test is ran but it ends up in "test failed" and the debugger says:

```
“MirageUITests” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture. Try installing a universal version of the bundle.
2021-07-08 00:04:33.819224+0530 MirageUITests-Runner[59250:3764976] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/jake/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mirage-bjcrubavwaoeufgtdntitbgnmgae/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MirageUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MirageUITests.xctest/MirageUITests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/jake/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mirage-bjcrubavwaoeufgtdntitbgnmgae/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MirageUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MirageUITests.xctest/MirageUITests: mach-o, but wrong architecture)
```

It seems that this UITest target only has mach-o arch. which is not enough. It also says, Try installing a universal version of the bundle but that is XCFramework where 1 bundle could pack both sim. and device archs. How can this be possible for simulator only use case?

Comment: I am also facing this kind of error when i run Unit test. How did you work around this?

Comment: Mostly upgraded the Xcode and fastlane as I was running the UItests via fastlane. But I am not sure if this fixed my issue or not.

Comment: did you find any fix for it? thank you